# Proof verification for proof by contraposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification

prove using contraposition that if a and b are integers:

$a^2-4b-2\neq0$

So the contrapositive:

$a^2-4b-2=0$ implies that at least one of either a or b are not integers

Working from the above, I got:

$a^2=4b+2$

$a^2=2(2b+1)$

If both a and b are integers, $2(2b+1)$ is a perfect square.

In other words:

$\sqrt{2(2b+1)}=k$

Where k is an integer

I also realised that 2b+1 is an odd number so:

$k=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2b+1}$

I ended my proof by saying that since 2b+1 is odd, it does not have a multiple of 2 so k will always have  multiple or $\sqrt{2}$ which means that it cannot be an integer.

Comment: Do you have to use contraposition? I think arithmetic mod 4 is an easier way to prove this. I'm not convinced by the end

Comment: Yeah, the homework question asked us to use contraposition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost done. You can conclude your proof as follows:

$a^2=2(2b+1)$ immediately implies, you have $a=2k, \thinspace k\in\mathbb Z$. Therefore, we have

$$4k^2=2(2b+1)\iff 2k^2=2b+1$$

which gives a contradiction.

Comment: Wouldn't that only apply to squares of even numbers?

Comment: Yes, but $a$ has to be even since $a^2$ is multiple of 2

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ was an integer, then it would be odd or even. If it was odd, then $a^2$ would be odd too, and then it cannot be of the form $2(2b+1)$ for some integer $b$. And if $a$ is even, then $a^2$ is multiple of $4$, and therefore it also cannot be of the form $2(2b+1)$ for some integer $b$.

I don't know what is it that you mean when you write that “$k$ will always have an irrational multiple, namely $\sqrt2$”.

Comment: I meant that it was impossible to get rid of the sqrt(2) since 2b+1 is odd. Sorry if it was confusing